# How to add a composite constraint when a column is false

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I tried both

1)

```
ALTER TABLE artikal_normativi
  ADD CONSTRAINT "artikal_normativi_UIX" 
  UNIQUE(artikal_proizvod_id, artikal_materijal_id) 
WHERE deleted = false;
```

2)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX artikal_normativi_UIX
  ON artikal_normativi
  USING btree(artikal_proizvod_id, artikal_materijal_id) 
  WHERE deleted = false;

ADD CONSTRAINT artikal_normativi_uix_constraint UNIQUE USING INDEX artikal_normativi_uix;
```

Both give me errors.

Error for the first statement:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 2: ...UNIQUE(artikal_proizvod_id, artikal_materijal_id) WHERE dele...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

And the second statement:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 1: ...i ADD CONSTRAINT artikal_normativi_uix_constraint USING INDE...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "USING"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 79
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the exact and complete error message you got

Comment: MySQL does not support partial indexes.

Comment: it looks like you already have duplicate records table. can you verify?

Comment: Why the `add constraint` in the second case? You already have a unique index that does what you want. No need to add the constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have UNIQUE constraint with partial index.

From [create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) we can see in UNIQUE constraint definition that inline index syntax is:

> UNIQUE ( column_name [, ... ] ) index_parameters |

And then index_parameters in UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, and EXCLUDE constraints are:

```
[ INCLUDE ( column_name [, ... ] ) ]
[ WITH ( storage_parameter [= value] [, ... ] ) ]
[ USING INDEX TABLESPACE tablespace_name ]
```

So no place for partial index (WHERE condition).

In your second attempt you forgot about `ALTER TABLE artikal_normativi`, so:

```
ALTER TABLE artikal_normativi
ADD CONSTRAINT artikal_normativi_uix_constraint UNIQUE USING INDEX artikal_normativi_uix;
```

But then you will have different problem, and that is limitation of constraints, including UNIQUE:

From description of [*ADD table_constraint_using_index*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

> The index **cannot** have expression columns nor **be a partial index**. Also,
>   it must be a b-tree index with default sort ordering. These
>   restrictions ensure that the index is equivalent to one that would be
>   built by a regular ADD PRIMARY KEY or ADD UNIQUE command.